# Unique key constraint while uploading data through application

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Am trying to upload 60 records of data through java web application to oracle database. While loading for fewer records lets say less than 15 records it is getting loaded and it is successful but when i try to load more than 15 records then am getting error like unique key constraint. There is a composite key in a table but data is different. It gets uploaded all records through import statement in SQL developer but not through application.

I tried this piece of code which is given in this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/

Anyone please suggest me how to go about.

JSP page

```
<%
                    String path=request.getParameter("file");
                    //String file_path="C:\\Users\\pallavi123\\Desktop\\fileupload\\"+path;
                    String file_path="C:\\fileupload\\"+path;
                    //String file_path="C:\\Users\\Etree\\Desktop\\fileupload\\"+path;
                    System.out.println("absolute_path: "+path);
                    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader(getCon());

                    loader.loadCSV(file_path, "CMPSS_FORMTABLE",false);
                %>
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CSVLoader {


private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

private char seprator;
//static private Connection connection=null;
private JdbcTemplate connection;

public CSVLoader() {
JdbcTemplate connection=new DbConnection().getJdbctemplate();
this.connection = connection;
//Set default separator
this.seprator = ',';
}

public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName,boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

CSVReader csvReader = null;
if(null == this.connection) {
    throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
}
try {       
    csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "+ e.getMessage());
}

String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

if (null == headerRow) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("No columns defined in given CSV file. Please check the CSV file format.");
}

String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks.length() - 1);

String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
query = query
        .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

System.out.println("Query: " + query);

String[] nextLine;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    con = (Connection) this.connection;
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

    if(truncateBeforeLoad) {
        //delete data from table before loading csv
        con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
    }

    final int batchSize = 10000;
    int count = 0;
    Date date = null;
    while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

        if (null != nextLine) {
            int index = 1;
            for (String string : nextLine) {
                date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                if (null != date) {
                    ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
                } else {
                    ps.setString(index++, string);
                }
            }
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
    con.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    con.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception("Error occured while loading data from file to database."+ e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (null != ps)
        ps.close();
    if (null != con)
        con.close();

    csvReader.close();
}
}

public char getSeprator() {
return seprator;
}

public void setSeprator(char seprator) {
this.seprator = seprator;
}


}
```

Comment: Its there in the link shared with u

Comment: Alexander, Please check my edit

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Late response from my end..... It is throwing unique key constraint violated

Comment: error at console and on page is "java.lang.Exception: Error occured while loading data from file to database.ORA-00001: unique constraint (COMPASS2.COMPOSITE_KEY_FORMTABLE) violated"